# MDTextField in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

everyone! I am new to `AutoLayout`. So here is cell which I create a `MDTextField` in.

```
@implementation PersonInfoCell

 -(instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    [self createCellItems];
}

return self;
}

-(void)createCellItems{
self.nameTextField = [[MDTextField alloc] init];

self.nameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameTextField];


[self.nameTextField mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_left).offset(100);
    make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_right).offset(-15);
    make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).offset(60);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(-20);
}];

}
```

Then in `UITableViewController` I create cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

PersonInfoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PersonInfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}


return cell;

}
```

In result I have the bottom line of `MDTextField` (which is OK), and the same parallel line as bottom line several pixels above. Just a gray line. No clue why it happens. Anyone help?

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, my colleague made it himself